# How to handle Timer or wait in bot composer for IVR chatbot

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm implementing an IVR Skype bot using Microsoft bot Composer. In a particular dialog, I need to take input from the user (voice message of the user) where that input may vary for at least 5 mins to 7 mins till that particular time bot should wait. After the 7th min bot needs to send a message and the bot needs to take input that was spoken and store it in a variable and trigger another dialog.

Here I'm not sure how to handle this situation.  Where bot needs to wait for 7 mins for all the user input and then the bot needs to send a message even if the user has completed his input or not.

Please suggest to me an idea of how to implement this situation? Do we have any Wait or Timer jobs in the composer to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried 'Delay' activity ?

Comment: A fair warning, Skype bots for Bot Framework are deprecated.

Comment: @VinothRajendran do you have any idea that we can call two dialogs simultaneously. so that one dialog I can take input and in another dialog I will throw user a message with delay response, will that way it works?

Comment: @VinothRajendran was able to configure it, actually in my case bot should not delay the response rather it should take the input of the user for 7 mins and then the bot should show the response.